# Change URL in CakePHP

Tags: php, url, cakephp

I have a Page in Cakephp that looks like

```
www.example.com/posts/next_posts
```

i.e. I have `app/View/posts/next_posts.ctp`

but I have Categories1, Categories2, Categories3,.... in Database.

How do I change the URL so that I assign a Variable of Database and it looks like

```
www.example.com/categories1/next_posts

www.example.com/categories2/next_posts

www.example.com/categories3/next_posts
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the router. Read this chapter:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

It will map a URL to a controller and action and passes arguments based on the URL. There are examples on that page as well if you're looking for that.